# R: Create & assign duplicate records

Tags: r, duplicates, uniqueidentifier

I have a series of media sources to which I must assign county names. For certain sources with only a single county assignment (e.g. local newspapers), this was fairly simple -- I created a county name variable based on a `switch` function which assigned county names based on source name. sample:

```
switchfun <- function(x) {switch(x, 'Morning Call' = 'Lehigh', 'Inquirer' =     
'Philadelphia', 'Daily Ledger' = 'Mercer', 'Null') }

County.Name <- as.character(lapply(Source, switchfun))
```

But I have sources (NPR, AP, etc) that I want to assign to all counties in my dataset. This is in essence replicating any record whose source is "national", and assigning the record to every county in my dataset.

`dput` of current file layout:

```
structure(list(Source = structure(c(5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 6L
), .Label = c("Associated Press", "Daily Ledger", "Herald Tribune", 
"Inquirer", "Morning Call", "NPR", "Yahoo News"), class = "factor"), 
County = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Lehigh", 
"Mercer", "Montgomery", "Philadelphia"), class = "factor"), 
Score = c(3L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 6L)), .Names = c("Source", 
"County", "Score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

In the current file NPR, Associated Press, & Yahoo News have no associated county ("NA").

`dput` of desired file layout:

```
structure(list(Source = structure(c(5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Associated Press", 
"Daily Ledger", "Herald Tribune", "Inquirer", "Morning Call", 
"NPR", "Yahoo News"), class = "factor"), County = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Lehigh", 
"Mercer", "Montgomery", "Philadelphia"), class = "factor"), Score = c(3L, 
10L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), .Names = c("Source", 
"County", "Score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

In the desired layout, I have assigned each national source & its score to each of the four counties in the dataset. e.g. Yahoo News & its score of 1 is replicated 4 times & associated w/ Lehigh, Philadelphia, Montgomery, & Mercer Counties. And the record with Yahoo News having County of "NA" disappears. In my actual dataset I have about 100 counties, so Yahoo News & its associated variables (e.g. Score, Date, Author, etc. -- I have about 60 variables total) would be replicated 100 times. I also want the Counties for these newly "duplicated" records to be assigned into the County.Name variable, which I created using the `switch` function above. I don't want 2 County Name fields, I want all these newly created Counties under County.Names.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide us with some sample data and show the desired result.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `merge`, but it's hard to say without a better representation of your data.

Comment: sorry, it was late & i was tired. updated w/ more explanation & `dput` readouts for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, this may be one possibility:

```
# a (minimal) data frame with all unique source-county combinations
src_cnt <- data.frame(source = c("Morning Call", "AP", "AP", "AP"), county = c("Lehigh", "Lehigh", "Mercer", "Phila"))

# a data frame with a unique score for each source
src_score <- data.frame(source = c("Morning Call", "AP"), score = c(10, 3))

merge(src_cnt, src_score)
```

**Edit** following the updated question:

```
# Assuming your current data is named dd
# select the national sources, i.e. the sources where County is missing
src_national <- dd$Source[is.na(dd$County)])

# select unique counties
counties <- unique(dd$County[!is.na(dd$County)])

# create all combinations of national sources and counties
src_cnt <- expand.grid(Source = src_national, County = counties)

# add score from current data to national sources
src_cnt2 <- merge(src_cnt, dd[is.na(dd$County), c("Source", "Score")], by = "Source")

# add national sources to local sources in dd
dd2 <- rbind(dd[!is.na(dd$County), ], src_cnt2)

# order by Sourcy and County
# assuming desired data is named `desired`
library(plyr)
desired2 <- arrange(df = desired, Source, County) 
dd2 <- arrange(df = dd2, Source, County)
all.equal(desired2, dd2)
```

For the very last part of your question you can just `rbind` the national sources in `src_cnt` to `County.Name`, or select relevant variables from `dd2`

Comment: I actually had a unique ID that also needed to be accounted for, so I modified to: `src_cnt<-expand.grid(Source=src_natl$Source, ID=src_natl$ID,County=counties) # where counties<-c('County1'...'County120')`; then `src_cnt2<-merge(src_cnt, src_natl, by = c("ID", "Source"))`, which filtered out `src_cnt` to only combinations of ID & Source from the original dataset.